# My chat room has been deleted without informing me and without telling the reason?

Tags: support, chat, area-51, moderator-tools, moderators

My [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29310/remote-sensing-and-photogrammetry-proposal-discussion) has been deleted without a message of the moderators about the reason
But I think the reason is that, it was a duplicate of [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27633/remote-sensing-experts-room)
In fact I wanted to move [the latter chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27633/remote-sensing-experts-room) from Stack Exchange to Area51 but because I didn't know how, I created a new one in area51
Is their a way to ask the moderator to retrieve [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29310/remote-sensing-and-photogrammetry-proposal-discussion) and delete [this one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/27633/remote-sensing-experts-room) instead? Or move [it](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/27633/remote-sensing-experts-room) to area51? because that kind of discussion is more related to area51

Comment: Chat rooms are not meant to be just placeholder for automatic feeds.

Comment: There **is** a message, right there in the chat room: *This room has been automatically deleted for inactivity*

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes for your interest in the process.  I upvoted your question as well as the answer.  I had a similar question concerning chat rooms and their life cycles and purposes.  Sorry for all the downvotes, but glad for the Q&A.

Answer (score 27):

Your chatroom had been deleted due to inactivity.

From the [Chat FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention): (emphasis mine)

> Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room. A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users.
>
> Rooms not worth retaining **which are inactive for 7 days will be deleted.** Rooms worth retaining which are inactive for 14 days will be frozen. Frozen rooms do not allow any new messages to be sent, and are not shown in the default room list to prevent cluttering the rooms interface.

However, your room had only 1 user who posted a message, so it was deleted by the system. Feeds that post messages into the room do not count as an additional user.

---

As a quick note, chatrooms are used for talking. People who have never posted a message into the room won't get any pings that you attempt to use. The fact that you've had multiple rooms, some of which were frozen or deleted is a sign that to develop your proposal, you should think of other various ways. I'm not trying to sound rude, but empty chatrooms don't usually help a growing proposal.

Helpful tip: Try only having a single active chatroom at a time, invite multiple interested users who look forward to developing the proposal, and try growing the proposal in other ways.

Comment: Was going to post this myself, but you beat me to it.

Comment: Is there any way to move the other room from stack exchange to area51?

Comment: And how did you understand the reason? Because seems that you're not one of the moderators?

Comment: @sepideh The FAQ is available for everyone, not only moderators, and the room activity is also public.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I create a chat room and invite others to talk. It will take a while to attract people. Any way is there any way to move the other chat room from stackexchange to area 51?

Comment: @sepideh not sure about moving whole chat room, and sounds like it doesn't worth the effort to begin with.

Comment: @sepideh I'm a moderator, so I have the ability to see these sorts of things. You can move chat rooms (it's not really moving, as they are all on `chat.stackexchange.com`, but you change the parent site). I'm reluctant to do so however, because there isn't much that is productive going on in those chatrooms. Pings that don't ping, and just a list of things that doesn't speak to anyone. Chatrooms are for chatting, not to lie around and "hope" to attract people; they're not good walking ads. Have productive conversations in chatrooms. If you want to chat, chat then and there, don't wait up.